How can I extract the runtime parameter name from azure devops? I want to extract the webhook name that triggered the pipeline?
I am trying to extract the webhook that triggered the pipeline since azure sent this info in the runtime parameter in JSON format. I want to retrieve the name.

I tried to convert the parameter as follows:
echo ${{ convertToJson(parameters) }} | sed -E 's/^([^:]+) :.*/\1/  ```

to resume I have 2 webhooks in my pipeline and I want to retrieve the webhook that triggered the pipeline to choose which job will execute

I tried this  simple test **yet it keep skipping without any output:


resources:
   webhooks:
     - webhook: webhook1
       connection: ServiceConnection1
     - webhook: webhook2
       connection: ServiceConnection2

 trigger:
   branches:
     include:
       - main

 stages:
   - stage: Stage1
     condition: eq(variables['resources.webhooks[2].webhook'], 'webhook1')
     jobs:
       - job: Job1
         steps:
           - script: echo "This stage is triggered by webhook1"

   - stage: Stage2
     condition: eq(variables['resources.webhooks[2].webhook'], 'webhook2')
     jobs:
       - job: Job1
         steps:
           - script: echo "This stage is triggered by webhook2" ```



How can I extract the runtime parameter name from azure devops? I want to extract the webhook name that triggered the pipeline?

To meet your requirement, you can use the Pipeline variable: Resources.TriggeringAlias. It will show the webhook name that trigger the pipeline.
Here is an example:
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: webhook1        
      connection: ServiceConnection1   
    - webhook: webhook2
      connection: ServiceConnection2

stages:
- stage: Stage1
  condition: eq(variables['RESOURCES.TRIGGERINGALIAS'], 'webhook1')
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:
    - script: echo "This stage is triggered by webhook1"

- stage: Stage2
  condition: eq(variables['RESOURCES.TRIGGERINGALIAS'], 'webhook2')
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:
    - script: echo "This stage is triggered by webhook2" 

When the pipeline is triggered by one of the webhook, it will run the target stage.
Result:

